# Django - variables in template without whitespace

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I am getting 3 variables rendered to template which should be shown next to each other with whitespace in between if they exist. I tried:

```
"{{v1|default:''}} {{v2|default:''}} {{v3|default:''}}"
```

But if `v1` doesnot exist, i have `" v2_value v3_value"`.

What I need is always: `"any_value any_value"` meaning - without any whitespaces at the start and end parts. How can I achieve this?

I could do all possible permutations, but i hope, there is more elegant way of doing this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First, you could pass the template a list instead of the three separate variables and use:

```
{{yourlist|join:" "}}
```

But I don't like that approach, because you'd have to create the list in the view, that's messy.

The second and better option would be to create a custom **template tag**. For example, create a module `templatetags` in your app and create a file called `main_extras.py`. Add the following code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def join_vars(*args, **kwargs):
    separator = kwargs['separator']
    return separator.join(str(x) for x in args)
```

Then, in your template you can use it like this:

```
{% load main_extras %}    

<pre>"{% join_vars v1 v2 v3 separator="/" %}"</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

what about `' '.join([v1, v2, v3])` outsite the template, in view?

you could also use [join](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join) tag: `list_of_values|join:' '`

Creating a list from seperate values is also posiible, but requires cutsom tag. Please check:

- [Creating a list on the fly in a Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715550/creating-a-list-on-the-fly-in-a-django-template)