# How to get object attribute in django template for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

How can you do the Django template equivalent to this python for loop?

```
    extra_context = [o.extra_context for o in activities]
```

or do I need to register a new template tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around and reading some documentation, here's my approach

```
{% for a in activities %}
    {% with a.extra_context as o %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new list variable to iterate over, you need access to the template's context - which I don't think you can do from the template itself. As far as I know that must be done from the view. [This question may provide more insight. The discussion of template tags found in the same thread is also relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715550/creating-a-list-on-the-fly-in-a-django-template)

If `activities` is the only thing being passed through the request context, then I believe the closest thing you can do from within the template without registering a new tag is:

```
{% for o in activities %}
    {{ o.extra_context }}
    <!-- do stuff -- >
{% endfor %}
```

I would refer to the above-linked thread for discussion on making a tag that can work with a new list, etc.