# Is it possible to use a freshly created context variable anywhere in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

For a long time now, I have been trying to figure out how to work with lists created *on the fly* in Django templates, meaning being able to:

- create a list directly in a django template,
- add new elements to that list,
- concatenate 2 lists together.

Those lists should be able to handle django objects and not only simple strings or so. For instance, in my case, I wanted my lists to be able to store form fields (example to follow).

After many researches, I figured out that it was impossible to do that but with simple things, and that I had to create my own custom tags if I ever wanted to achieve my purpose. My custom tag is written below. Please notice that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715794/8210450) helped me to do so.

### The issue I am facing with

The custom tag works, and I use it in a `for loop`. The list generated here is correctly evolving according to the loop, and I can call it like any variable while still being **in** the loop (because it was exported in Django context): **{{ listName }}**

But! Once I'm outside that loop, my list does not seem having being updated at all! Like if it was only existing inside the for loop... I thought at first that when something was defined into a Django template context, it was available anywhere inside the template, and not only inside the block where it was defined. **Am I missing something? Is that the normal behaviour for Django?** I have not been able to find the answer to that question.

### Custom tag

```
@register.tag()
def setList(parser, token):
    """
    Use : {% setList par1 par2 ... parN as listName %}
    'par' can be a simple variable or a list
    To set an empty list: {% setList '' as listName %}
    """
    data = list(token.split_contents())
    if len(data) >= 4 and data[-2] == "as":
        listName = data[-1]
        items = data[1:-2]
        return SetListNode(items, listName)
    else:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "Erreur ! L'utilisation de %r est la suivante : {%% setList par1 par2 ... parN as listName %%}" % data[0]
        )

class SetListNode(template.Node):

  def __init__(self, items, listName):
      self.items = []
      for item in items: self.items.append(template.Variable(item))
      self.listName = listName

  def render(self, context):
      finalList = []
      for item in self.items:
          itemR = item.resolve(context)
          if isinstance(itemR, list): finalList.extend(itemR)
          elif itemR == '': pass
          else: finalList.append(itemR)
      context[self.listName] = list(finalList)
      return "" # django doc : render() always returns a string
```

### Use of my custom tag in a Django Template

```
{% setList '' as new_list %}
new_list value is: {{ new_list }} # shows me an empty list: OK!

# then I iter on a forms.RadioSelect field
{% for field in form.fields %}
  {% if field.choice_label in some_other_list %}
    {% setList new_list field as new_list %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ new_list }} # a new item is added to new_list when necessary: OK!
{% endfor %}

{{ new_list }} # just shows an empty list, the one from the begining: THE ISSUE!
```

So: it looks like that my initial list is just being updated locally in my `for loop`. What a disappointment! **Any idea about how I could use my *custom list* outside the loop? Is it impossible?**

Thank you so much for the time you will take to help me with that thing. First time I am posting something in here, so if one needs anything please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a solution!

Well,  after spending hard time understanding and printing everything I could to understand what was going on, I finally succeeded in doing so! Thanks a lot to **@Siegmeyer** who really helped me to see clear in what was really a Django `Context` object.

To begin with, you can have a look at **Django Template Context source code** over [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/_modules/django/template/context/).
As @Siegmeyer said, `Context` in Django works as a stack. You won't be able to use it as a classic dictionary, especially if you want to add variables to your context. Please read @Siegmeyer explanations, it was clear enough for me. Also, he/she told me the answer without giving me the one existing appropriate method dedicated to my need, but maybe that was on purpose to make me read harder the doc ;-) Which would have been a good thing after all.

Let's have a look at that method of the `BaseContext` (from `django.template.context` source code) I am writing about :

```
def set_upward(self, key, value):
        """
        Set a variable in one of the higher contexts if it exists there,
        otherwise in the current context.
        """
        context = self.dicts[-1]
        for d in reversed(self.dicts):
            if key in d.keys():
                context = d
                break
        context[key] = value
```

As you can see, `set_upward` method answers perfectly to my need (the custom list is in a higher context). Except that it seems it is only looking at the *n-1* context, so if you define your custom variable too deep in `for` loops, you might not be able to access it at some higher level (>*n-1*, but I did not test that). Maybe a good thing to avoid that would be to define your needed variables in your `context_processors.py` file so it can be accessible anywhere in your template (not sure about that though).

---

### Custom tag: the end

Finally, my custom tag allowing me to define lists *on the fly* is the one following:

```
@register.tag()
def setList(parser, token) [...] # no change, please see my question


class SetListNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, items, listName):
        self.items = []
        for item in items: self.items.append(template.Variable(item))
        self.listName = listName

    def render(self, context):
        finalList = []
        for item in self.items:
            itemR = item.resolve(context)
            if isinstance(itemR, list): finalList.extend(itemR)
            elif itemR == '': pass
            else: finalList.append(itemR)
        context.set_upward(self.listName, list(finalList))
        return "" # django doc : render() always return a string
```

The usecase of my question works, the custom list is displaying what is required.

If anything is not clear, or if you think I might be missing something, please feel free to tell me! Anyway, thanks for reading!

Comment: It's not only looking at context `n-1`, it is traversing all contexts upwards until it finds one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's a great question.

Now to the business: `Context` object (a dictionary mapping variable names to variable values) is a **stack**. That is, you can `push()` it and `pop()` it.

With that knowledge let's look at the code once again:

```
# Enter scoped block.
# Push new_list as empty list onto the context stack.
{% setList '' as new_list %}
new_list value is: {{ new_list }}

# Enter for-loop scoped block.
{% for field in form.fields %}
  {% if field.choice_label in some_other_list %}
    # Push new new_list onto context.
    {% setList new_list field as new_list %}
  {% endif %}

  # Print most current value named new_list (at the top)
  {{ new_list }}

# Exit for-loop.
# Pop the loop variables pushed on to the context to avoid
# the context ending up in an inconsistent state when other
# tags (e.g., include and with) push data to context.
{% endfor %}

# new_list's value is again empty list, 
# since all other values under that name were poped off the stack.
{{ new_list }}

# Pop any values left.
# Exit scoped block.
```

#### What's this all about?, from [`django.template.base`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/620e9dd31a2146d70de740f96a8cb9a6db054fc7/django/template/base.py) source code:

> How [Django template system] works:
>
> The `Lexer.tokenize()` function converts a template string (i.e., a
>   string containing markup with custom template tags) to tokens, which
>   can be either plain text (`TOKEN_TEXT`), variables (`TOKEN_VAR`) or
>   block statements (`TOKEN_BLOCK`).
>
> The `Parser()` class takes a list of tokens in its constructor, and
>   its `parse()` method returns a compiled template -- which is, under
>   the hood, a list of `Node` objects.
>
> Each `Node` is responsible for creating some sort of output -- e.g.
>   simple text (`TextNode`), variable values in a given context
>   (`VariableNode`), results of basic logic (`IfNode`), results of
>   looping (`ForNode`), or anything else. The core `Node` types are
>   `TextNode`, `VariableNode`, `IfNode` and `ForNode`, but plugin modules
>   can define their own custom node types.
>
> Each `Node` has a `render()` method, which takes a `Context` and
>   returns a string of the rendered node. For example, the `render()`
>   method of a `VariableNode` returns the variable's value as a string.
>   The `render()` method of a `ForNode` returns the rendered output of
>   whatever was inside the loop, recursively.
>
> The `Template` class is a convenient wrapper that takes care of
>   template compilation and rendering.

So, in sum, what `ForNode` does is:
It takes some mark-up code (whatever is inside `for` tags), pushes some variables on the stack, compiles HTML with them, pops off introduced variables off the stack and returns said HTML.

*Additionally, you can have a look at `ForNode`'s `render` implementation [itself](https://github.com/django/django/blob/21046e77734278cea871dce922220bf29aa5b7b4/django/template/defaulttags.py). It takes `context` as argument and returns `mark_safe(''.join(nodelist))`, which is a string.

Sadly, you cannot circumvent this mechanism. Unless you write your own completely.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I did not know that context used to work as a stack (and the push/pop explanation makes a lot of sense now, for how my code does not do what I want).

Oops: 'enter' key posted my comment, I had other stuff to say! Editiin my comment right now :-)

Comment: Ok I am a real newbie so I can only edit my comment within 5 minutes apparently... So here is the continuation:

If I get it right, anything *new* defined in a for loop will only be accessible inside the loop, because the new variable wil be pushed at the begining and poped at the end: ok. 

But then as context is a dictionary, I should still be able to access a specific variable of it and be able to modify it, even in a for loop. My guess is that in my code I am not accessing an existing context variable, but defining a new one and pushing it into context from the begining

Comment: "If I get it right, anything new defined in a for loop will only be accessible inside the loop" - correct. "I should still be able to access a specific variable of it and be able to modify it" - not quite. You cannot **modify** variable (permanently), only change it's meaning (shadow it) in the current block by pushing **new** variable under the same name. "[...] in my code I am not accessing an existing context variable, but defining a new one and pushing it into context" - exactly.

Comment: To be more specific: `context` is a list so is a mutable object I can work with (I can work with the reference). So to me I should be able to append element to `context[self.listName]`.. I think what's wrong is the way I define recursively `new_list`: `context[self.listName] = list(finalList)` just change the value and not the reference... and to me that's why `new_list` content is not being updated at all. I think I work and alter a list  freshly defined in the `for loop`, and not with the `new_list` actually defined before the loop... I will investigate that later!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment before I post my last one. I think I understand what you're telling me. I get that I am just "pushing new variable under the same name" (and I did not know that before). But now I think I should be able to access a context variable defined before the `for loop`, then being able to alter it inside the `for loop` (by working with its reference and not just pushing a new var under the same name), and finally being able to access to it (modified) after the `for loop`.

Comment: To do that you would have to hack your way around context implementation. Under the hood, context is actually a stack of dictionaries. Take a look at `__setitem__` method: `self.dicts[-1][key] = value` - it assigns value to key in the top dictionary - your current scoped block (for loop). So, to "be able to access a context variable defined before the for loop" you would have to access earlier dictionaries.

Comment: Also, if you find this answer useful and constructive, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Comment: Sorry if I look simply-minded, I have read 100 times your answers in order to understand what's going on, and I am still learning something each time I read them! "context is actually a stack of dictionaries": wow ok if that's true and if for each new "set of tags" a new dictionary is being created and added to the top of context stack, it makes sense that I won't be able to do what I want. I will try to read harder the doc, even if it's becoming a little be too advanced for me.

I upvoted but as I am new here, my upvote is not being publically taken into account.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit advanced topic. I find reading source code more enlightening than reading docs, since they explain usage rather than implementation.